# 静的ライブラリプロジェクトのテンプレート関数の明示的インスタンス化できません。

Tags: c++, visual-c++, clang

visual studio2022を用いて、静的ライブラリを生成するプロジェクト(ProjectLib)とそのlibを参照する実行ファイルのプロジェクト(ProjectExe)を開発しています。

**ProjectLibは以下のファイルを含みます。**

projectlib.h

```
#pragma once
template<typename T>
void func(T t);
```

projectlib.cpp

```
#include "projectlib.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <variant>

template<typename T>
void func(T t) {
  std::cout << t;
}

struct Instantiate {
  void  operator()() {
      std::variant<int, std::string> v;
      std::visit([](auto v) { func(v); }, v);
  }
};
```

上記のファイルではテンプレート関数funcに対してstruct Instantiateを用いてint, std::string型のインスタンス化をしています。

**ProjectExe**
main.cpp

```
#include "lib.h"
#pragma comment(lib, "ProjectLib.lib")

int main()
{ 
  int i = 10;
  std::string s = "test";
  func(i);
  func(s);
}
```

main.cppではProjectLib.libをリンクしてインスタンス化したint, std::string型のfuncを使用します。

**問題**
上記の書き方の場合、vc++では正常にビルドできるのですが、clangを使用したときにProjectExeビルド時にfuncのインスタンスのシンボルを解決できずにリンクエラーになることです。

**回避策1**
回避策として、Instantiateの宣言をprojectlib.hに記述して、void Instantiate::operator()()の定義をprojectlib.cppに記述ことですが、それは避けたい回避策です。

**回避策2**
明示的インスタンス化を使用して、各型に対応するインスタンスを生成することもできますが、今後型が増えるたびにメンテナンスする必要があるので、この回避策も避けたいです。
template void func(int t);

インスターフェースを汚さずにcppファイル内でインスタンス化する方法はありますでしょうか？

～～～～～最終コード～～～～

```
// projectlib.h
class Func
{
private:
struct Instantiate;

public:
template <typename T>
static void func(T t);
}
```

```
// projectlib.cpp
template <typename T>
void Func::func(T t) { ... }

struct Func::Instantiate
{
  void operator()();
}

void Func::Instantiate::operator()() 
{
  // if(false) {
  std::variant<int, std::string> v;
  std::visit([](auto v) { func(v); }, v);
  //} //if(false)で囲った場合は実体化されない
}
```

Comment: `template` はソースコードレベルで使ってこそおいしいので DLL/LIB のように分離しちゃうのはそもそも想定されていない使い方だと思うっス。

Comment: ご指摘ありがとうございます。
しかし、既存コードがこのようになっており、おそらくコンパイル時間削減など意図があるものと思われます。

Comment: 正：「関数テンプレート」、誤：「テンプレート関数」、つまり `template` は関数のひな型であって、まだ関数ではないのでそれをライブラリの形で公開するというのは無理難題。既存コードの誤りを正すのは今しかないのでは？

Comment: 確かにその通りかもしれません。問題が出るまでは、774RRさんの修正方向で試してみようと思います。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ご存じのことも含まれるとは思いますが、まず前提として

- テンプレートはその翻訳単位で使っていれば実体化される (ポインタだけの利用など、実体が必要なければ実体化されない)
- 複数の翻訳単位に同一の実体があればリンクしたときにひとつに統合される
- `extern template` で指定することで実体化は抑制できる

というのが基本的なルールです。

この場合には質問者は `Instantiate::operator()` の中で `func<int>` と `func<std::string>` を使っていますから、この実体は既に存在していることになり、 `main.cpp` 内で `extern template` で指定すればこの翻訳単位で実体化を抑制しても問題ありません。

そしてもうひとつの重要なルールはクラス定義内でのメンバ関数定義は暗黙に `inline` 指定されたものとみなすということです。 つまり、この場合には `Instantiate::operator()`  にインライン指定が付いているわけですが、この関数自体が呼び出されていないので実体も作られず、故にそこから呼ばれる関数テンプレートも実体化されていないのだと考えられます。

解決するためにはクラス定義の外で `Instantiate::operator()` を定義すれば良いでしょう。

これらを統合してソースコードで表すと

```cpp
// main.cpp
#include <string>
#include "lib.h"

extern template void func<int>(int);
extern template void func<std::string>(std::string);

int main()
{ 
  int i = 10;
  std::string s = "test";
  func<int>(i);
  func<std::string>(s);
}
```

```cpp
// projectlib.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <variant>
#include <string>
#include "lib.h"

template<typename T>
void func(T t) {
  std::cout << t;
}

struct Instantiate {
  void operator()(void);
};

void Instantiate::operator()(void) {
    std::variant<int, std::string> v;
    std::visit([](auto v) { func(v); }, v);
}
```

```cpp
// lib.h
#pragma once

template<typename T>
void func(T t);
```

というような要領です。

Comment: 上記回答について、追加の質問なのですが、
projectlib.cppにてInstantiate, void Instantiate::operator()の定義を無名名前空間で囲った場合に、上記のコードは再度、リンクエラーになるコードになってしまいます。
考えられる原因としては、
1, 関数テンプレートfuncのインスタンスが無名名前空間内に作成され、外部ファイルからの参照ができない。
2, 無名空間内で内部リンケージを持つInstantiateが参照されていないため、インスタンス化されないため、funcもインスタンス化されない。
という、推測を持っていますが、
Instantiateを無名名前空間に置きながら、funcのインスタンス化を達成する方法はありますでしょうか？

Comment: func 自体はグローバルにあり、グローバルな名前空間で解釈されるはずなので 1 の理由ではないですね。
また、無名名前空間は便宜的に名前空間の表記法をとるものの実際には内部リンケージになるというだけです。
内部リンケージになることによってどこからも使われないことが (コンパイラによって) 確信できる状態なので除去されたと考えるべきでしょう。

クラステンプレートの一部のメンバしか使っていない場合に使われていないメンバを実体化しないことがありうるというのは言語仕様に記述があるのですが、このような普通の (メンバ) 関数が使われていないときに付随するテンプレートの実体化を抑制するのが許されるのは変な話ですね。 私は仕様上にそれが許される記述を見つけることが出来ません。 (許されないと断言できるほど仕様に詳しいわけではないです。)

現実に目の前にある処理系の挙動がこうなっている以上は対処しないと仕方がないんですが、使われない関数によって間接的に実体化を期待するよりは明示的実体化のほうが綺麗なように思えます。 型が増えるたびに対処する必要があるのは結局のところ同じなので、間接的な記述よりは明記されているほうが分かり易いと感じます。

Comment: 今後のためにメモとして残しておきます。
無名名前空間で囲われたコードは名前の衝突を防ぐ意図のみだったため、クラスに紐づけるなどして、回避しました。
また、clangではif(false)など自明で到達しないコードは実体化されないため、
Instantiate::operator()の中身をすべてif(false)で囲った場合はfuncの実態は作られません。